# GNU/Linux PureOS - How can I add more disk space?

Tags: gnu, pureos

I want to add more disk space to my computer. My disk partitions are shown below:

[image: My Disk]

How can I extend "Filesystem Partition 3 (105 GB Ext4)" to use the "Free Space (105 GB)", without losing any data?

Comment: Please open a terminal and run the following command: `df -m` so we can see how space is being used and free space. Please post the results in your reply.

Comment: Here's a picture: https://imgur.com/a/KPO1YuH

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to expand the root partition (/dev/sdb3). Trying to do this on a live system is difficult and inadvisable unless there is no other way (see [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-resize-ext4-root-partition-live-without-umount)).

A better idea is to reboot the system into [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) or (my preferred Swiss Army Knife) [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) and make the change with GParted.